# How does poker tracking software evaluates live hands

Tags: language-agnostic, poker

I'm just curious how they make this kind of software.

Do they?

- Capture the screen and use an OCR library to track hands
- Determine the memory locations of the hands and read it directly from there

Something else?

Edit/ I really mean live tracking, not using the hand histories

Comment: Intercepting network traffic may be an option. Although it's unlikely.

Comment: Mayby I should rephrase my question as what would be the simplest way to do this :p

Comment: @biziclop: *(disclaimer: I'm actually working on a (legit) poker tracking software)*.  Network traffic, at least for the big sites, is encrypted so attackers cannot access it (I wrote "attackers" because it's totally against the EULA of most sites to try to analyze a deal in real-time).

Comment: @TacticalCoder I was thinking along the lines of a custom network driver but that would fail for similar reasons if the encryption was implemented correctly. (And as there's a lot of money involved, I assume it was.)

Comment: Since the cards are in fixed positions, and have a very small number of options, an "OCR" would be dead-easy to write (it wouldn't actually be an OCR).
Maybe they should add Captcha-like drawings on the cards :P

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/30421166/1449460